# given a vector with different figures find out how many are circles and how many are squares

Tags: c++

So i got this example :

```
  class figures
    {};

    class square:public  figures
    {};

    class circle : public  figures
    {};


    .....

    int main()
    {
    geometric figures* *p;

    p[0]=new Circle;
    p[1]=new Square;

return 0;
    };
```

and so on. My question is how can i find out later how many circles or squares do I have in my geometric figure array if all the pointers are the geometric figures type?

Comment: multiple problems here... can't have spaces in identifier names (geometric figures), and, you never allocated the array 'p'. Maybe you're looking for std::vector instead?

Comment: Why not just keep running totals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dynamic casts. For example:

```
// Returns true if 'a' is of type 'square'
bool isSquare(Figure* a)
{
    return dynamic_cast<Square*>(a) != nullptr;
}
// Returns true if 'a' is of type 'circle'    
bool isCircle(Figure* a)
{
    return dynamic_cast<Circle*>(a) != nullptr;
}
int main()
{
    Figure *p = new Figure[5];
    p[0] = new Circle;
    p[1] = new Circle;
    p[2] = new Square;
    p[3] = new Square;
    p[4] = new Square;
    int circleCnt = 0;
    int squareCnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(isCircle(p[i]))
        {
            circleCnt++;
        }
        if(isSquare(p[i]))
        {
            squareCnt++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of circles: " << circleCnt << endl;
    cout << "Number of squares: " << squareCnt << endl;
}
```

The output of this program will be:
Number of circles: 2
Number of squares: 3

Note that **this is highly inefficient** compared to keeping the number of circles and squares up-to-date somewhere.

Comment: thank you ! I know is inefficient but actually the assignment was to view how many circles and squares are in the figures vector without counting them as i putt it in the vector. Is was like : given a vector with different figures find out how many are circles .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dynamic_cast`:

```
std::vector<geometric_figures *> shapes;
int num_circles = 0;
int num_squares = 0;
for (geometric_figures * shape : shapes)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<circle*>(shape))
        num_circles++;
    if(dynamic_cast<square*>)(shape))
        num_squares++;
}
```

You could also add an `enum` to correspond to the type of shape, and add a `GetType()` method that returns that `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an `enum` in your class

```
class geometric_figures
{
public:
    enum shape {eSquare, eCircle};
    virtual shape GetShapeType() const = 0;
};

class square : public geometric_figures
{
public:
    shape GetShapeType() const override { return eSquare; }
};

class circle : public geometric_figures
{
public:
    shape GetShapeType() const override { return eCircle; }
};
```

Then you can use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    using GF = geometric_figures;
    std::vector<GF*> p;

    p.push_back(new circle);
    p.push_back(new square);

    int num_circles = std::count_if(p.begin(), p.end(), [](GF const* fig){ return fig->GetShapeType() == GF::eCircle; });

}
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/6x3t)